# Good hash function for ordering sizes?

Tags: hash

I want a hash-function that orders things into buckets by size.  The sizes can be anywhere from 0 to INT_MAX and I can have up to 50 buckets or so.  How can I come up with a hash function that returns a bucket number from 0 to 49 or so given some size from 0 to INT_MAX, where the buckets are ordered by size. Bucket 0 has the smallest sizes, bucket 49 has the largest bucket sizes, etc.. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: huh? Just split the range 0..INT_MAX into 50 parts and there is your "hash function". if thing's size is within part 39, it goes into bucket 39

Comment: If I do that, it will require a huge set of if/else statements.  I'm looking for a one-line function that returns what bucket it should go into given a size.

Comment: maybe not one-liner, but can be easily done in 3-4 lines (including constants). Just use a bit of simple math. Try it, good exercise.